# Infopath; remove control boxes for print view

Tags: infopath

I have an Infopath form that is being used in several views. Eventually, this form must be printed out (As our network doesn't allow for digital signatures). For this printed view, is there any way to hide the box around the controls? I've combed the internet and most Infopath settings - I'm very willing to do coded solutions.